# On Firefox HTML input overflows on the right in a CSS grid

Tags: css, firefox, grid

My CSS grid has the following stylesheet :

```
<span id="declaration" class="declaration" style="grid-template-columns: 80px 10px 150px; grid-template-rows: 10px 10px 20px;">
.declaration {
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 20px;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
}
```

The leftmost element of the grid has the following stylesheet :

```
<input type="text" id="etiquette" class="etiquette" title="label" style="grid-column: 1 / auto; display: initial;">
.etiquette {
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

And my etiquette element overflows on the right :

[image]

This problem arises on Firefox (but not on Chrome neither on Opera).